# How can I sign a message(not transaction) from a dApp?

Tags: multiversx

When creating a dApp using MultiversX Network, I need to authenticate a user without actually sending a transaction.

For other blockchains like Ethereum this is achieved using MetaMask which can sign a message and you can be sure that the user is who he says he is.

I noticed that Elrond Wallet has a "Sign" feature but I'm unsure of how this would be used from the outside or how can I prompt the user to sign a message and send it back.

Can I use MultiversX extension or MultiversX Wallet to sign a message?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are not doing so already, I suggest you to use [erdjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@elrondnetwork/erdjs) or the [dapp package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@elrondnetwork/dapp) (which includes erdjs) to build your dapp.

Using those you will get the various signing providers that elrond made. This includes:

- [WalletConnectProvider](https://github.com/ElrondNetwork/elrond-sdk-erdjs/blob/main/src/dapp/walletConnectProvider.ts), which is used to login via the maiar app
- [ExtensionProvider](https://github.com/ElrondNetwork/elrond-sdk-erdjs/blob/main/src/dapp/extensionProvider.ts), which is used to login via a metamask like browser extension called the [maiar defi wallet](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/maiar-defi-wallet/dngmlblcodfobpdpecaadgfbcggfjfnm)
- [HWProvider](https://github.com/ElrondNetwork/elrond-sdk-erdjs/blob/main/src/dapp/hwProvider.ts), which is used to login via the ledger hardware

All of these providers allow you to login, sign transactions, send transactions and also to sign custom messages.

Example code to login via the ExtensionProvider:

```
let provider = ExtensionProvider.getInstance();
await provider.init();
let walletAddress = await provider.login();
let message = new SignableMessage({message: "Sign this message to make sure you are logged in"});
let signedMessage = await provider.signMessage(message);
```

Of course using the signed message in this case is optional, but can be useful if you plan to implement some server side authentication flow.

Comment: The sample code is EXACTLY what I've been looking for, but I must check on how this works in an Angular application as there have been some issues with the latest version of Angular as described in another question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69507043/is-there-a-fix-workaround-for-making-erdjs-work-with-angular-12

Will come back with results on how this worked for our system.

Answer (score 1):

Contributing to Martin W answer:

[dapp package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@elrondnetwork/dapp) is deprecated. Use [dapp-core](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@elrondnetwork/dapp-core) instead